# Add line break in Twitter (Android/Java)

Tags: android, twitter, line

I want to tweet some text to Twitter using line breaks.

I've tried `\n` or `\r` like in my code below, but Twitter is ignoring those.

`tweet.setText(" Text1 " + "\n" + "Text2");`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try `<br />` or `[br /]`.

`<br />` is the standard html tag, sometimes websites and forums use `[br /]`.